# Divide consecutive element in a nested list by consecutive elements in another list

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list that looks something like this:

```
list1=[[42, 432, 34, 242], [32, 68, 72, 90], [46, 78, 22, 24]]
```

and a flat list that looks something like this:

```
list2=[2,4,2,6]
```

How do I divided each consecutive element in list1 by each consecutive element in list2 (e.g. 42/2, 432/4, 34/2, 242/6) to get an output like this:

```
result=[[21,108,17,40],[16,17,36,15],[23,19,11,4]]
```

I have tried doing this:

```
for (item1, item2) in zip(list1, list2):
    avg_list.append(item1/item2)
```

but since list1 is a nested list there was some error in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
list1 = [[42, 432, 34, 242], [32, 68, 72, 90], [46, 78, 22, 24]]
list2 = [2,4,2,6]

result = [[int(x / y) for x, y in zip(lst, list2)] for lst in list1]
```

This is the output:

```
[[21, 108, 17, 40], [16, 17, 36, 15], [23, 19, 11, 4]]
```

Comment: Integer division `int(x / y)` could be `x // y`.

Comment: @frost-nzcr4 Not always. `int(-3/2) == -1`, `-3//2 == -2`

Comment: operator.floordiv `//` uses orientation in flooring from zero but it's ok for the question's positive numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I believe numpy does what you want "out-of-the-box":

```
import numpy as np
list1=[[42, 432, 34, 242], [32, 68, 72, 90], [46, 78, 22, 24]]
list2=[2,4,2,6]
np.divide(list1, list2).astype(int)
```

outputs:

```
array([[ 21, 108,  17,  40],
       [ 16,  17,  36,  15],
       [ 23,  19,  11,   4]])
```

If you want the result as a list of list simply do:
`np.divide(list1, list2).astype(int).tolist()`

Comment: Nice! Maybe you should also convert the array to a list of lists?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Something like below will work.

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list1)):
        list1[i][j] = int(list1[i][j] / list2[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a traditional way to do it:

```
list1=[[42, 432, 34, 242], [32, 68, 72, 90], [46, 78, 22, 24]]
list2=[2,4,2,6]

result = []
curr_list = []
for x in range(len(list1)):
    curr_list = []
    for y in range(len(list2)):
        curr_list.append(int(list1[x][y]/list2[x]))
    result.append(curr_list)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[21, 216, 17, 121], [8, 17, 18, 22], [23, 39, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without numpy you could use this?

```
list1=[[42, 432, 34, 242], [32, 68, 72, 90], [46, 78, 22, 24]]
list2=[2,4,2,6]
avg_list = []

for item in list1:
    results = []
    for i, divider in enumerate(list2):
        results.append(int(item[i]/divider))
    avg_list.append(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one with iterators with speed and memory optimizations:

```py
from collections import deque
from itertools import zip_longest
from operator import floordiv

result = deque(
    deque(map(floordiv, *both))
    for both in zip_longest(list1, (), fillvalue=list2)
)
```